# MVC3 (Razor) How to do something with json passed data in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I've passed my model in the View to the Controller with the following jQuery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        data: model,
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("createDoc")',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Done '+ result.toString());
        }
    });
```

The problem is: in the Controller method "createDoc"

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createDoc(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
    {
        CreateWordprocessingDocument(movies);
        return Json(new { result = movies.Count()});
    }
```

I can't do anything with the movies Enumerable data.
The call to the CreateWordProcessingDocument create a document with the movies data. But it does not.
This is the method code:

```
public void CreateWordprocessingDocument(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
{
    HttpContextWrapper context = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=example.doc");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document";
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<p  align='Center'><b> GENERAL TITLE</b></p>");
    sb.Append("<br>"+movies.Count());
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.Count(); i++) {
        sb.Append("<br>Title:" + movies.ElementAt(i).Title +"");
    }
    context.Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

But it doesn't work: it returns to the ajax post and pop ups the "Done" alert, with the result.tostring() showing the HTML code I create on the createWordProcessingDocument method.
How can I avoid this behaviour so I can do something with the data I pass to the controller from the View?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the movies Enumerable empty, or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you want to di instead?

Comment: @mfusseneggerthe movies Enumerable is not empty: it in fact has all the data I want. My problem is that in createDoc (and CreateWordProcessingDocument) I cannot create the document I used to and ask the user where he wants to save the file (or open it) like I used to do before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I post the solution here, if it can helps someone with my problem.
In my *createDoc* method I create the string with the wanted data, then I put them in a tempData proprierty. That's what *createDoc* looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void createDoc(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
    {
        String mov="";
        mov = mov + "<br>" + movies.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < movies.Count(); i++)
        {
           mov=mov+"<br>Title:" + movies.ElementAt(i).Title + "";
        }
        TempData["movies"] = mov;
    }
```

Then the "control" returns to the Ajax post method, and at the end of it I put this:

```
success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreateWordprocessingDocument","Movies")'
        }
```

So my Ajax post full code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postData() {
    var urlact = '@Url.Action("createDoc")';
    var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

    alert(model);
    alert(JSON.stringify(model));

    $.ajax({
        data: model,
        type: "POST",
        url: urlact,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreateWordprocessingDocument","Movies")'
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Now the "control" is redirect to the *CreateWordProcessingDocument* action, where I actually create the document:

```
public void CreateWordprocessingDocument()
    {
        string movies = TempData["movies"] as string;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=example.doc");
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document";
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<p  align='Center'><b>TITLE</b></p>");
        sb.Append(movies);
        context.Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

That's all. Thank u all for your help, hope that I can help someone with this solution.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net MVC includes a `FileResult` in order to return a file with a mime type to the browser.

Do something like this instead:

```
public ActionResult  createDoc(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
{
    byte[] fileContents = CreateFileFromMovies(movies);

    return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-word.document");
}
```

Instead of accessing the response directly, create the document as a byte array and return the content using the `File()` method.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work. It doesn't allow me to open a dialog window to open/save the file and it still pop ups with the result.toString() statement the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the HTML code you created in CreateWordprocessingDocument is because that is what you directly output to the HTTP Response. You then ended the response. Basically, you bypassed a lot of ASP.NET MVC by directly writing the response yourself.

Comment: So, how can I bypass this problem and create a document file (formatted as shown in CreateWordProcessingDocument) and ask the user if he wants to open/save it?

Comment: Now, the funny thing is I tried the @Dismissile solution (didn't work) and even if I don't use anymore the HTTP Response I have anyway the HTML code in the pop up alert.